# Mapping Generic Classes using NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to do the following, but it's complaining that the "classes referenced by 'extends' were not found". I think I need to having a mapping for each concrete type of Component but I can't specify the Attributes.Class twice..

The code is as follows:

```
[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Class(Table = "Components", Abstract = true,
    NameType = typeof (Component<ContentItem>))]
public abstract class Component<T> : IComponent<T> where T : ContentItem
{
    ...
}

[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.JoinedSubclass(Table = "ComponentA", ExtendsType = typeof(Component<ItemA>))]
public class ComponentA : Component<ItemA>
{
    ...
}

[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.JoinedSubclass(Table = "ComponentB", ExtendsType = typeof(Component<ItemB>))]
public class ComponentB : Component<ItemB>
{
    ...
}
```

Where ItemA and ItemB inherit from ContentItem and are all mapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't map an open generic type like this, i.e. one that has an unspecified type parameter `<T>`.  It just doesn't work.

Ayende discusses this in [more detail on his blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/14/NHibernate-and-Generic-Entities.aspx).

Comment: If I follow that article and hard-code the information in the Component`1.hbm.xml file, then it appears to work fine. I just don't know how to do it using the Mapping.Attributes annotation.

Annoyingly, T isn't actually mapped in the classes because it's not persisted by the database in this instance.

Comment: So it sounds like the persistent property of Component<T> do not actually depend on T.  If this is the case, separate them into a ComponentBase (which is mapped), have Component<T> derive from ComponentBase (which is not mapped) and then have your Component<ItemA> class mapped as a joined-subclass of ComponentBase.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing in the end. Thanks for your help.