# ActiveRecord with Interfaces crashes

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I am having problems using ActiveRecord with Interfaces. When I use it without interfaces everything is working but when I use it with interfaces it works sometimes and not sometimes and it is very random. If it works it will continue work until a do some changes somewhere in my project and recompile. Then if it stops working it won't work until I do some unrelated changes again and recompile.
You can see my models below. Do you have any idea of how I can resolve this?

```
    [ActiveRecord]
    public class ContactInformation : ActiveRecordValidationBase<ContactInformation>
    {
        public ContactInformation()
        {
            Emails = new List<Email>();
}
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [HasMany(typeof(Email), Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan, "type='1'")]
        private IList<Email> Emails { get; set; }



   [ActiveRecord("Details",
    DiscriminatorColumn = "int",
    DiscriminatorType = "type",
    DiscriminatorValue = "1")]
    public class Email : Detail<Email>

   [ActiveRecord("Details",
    DiscriminatorColumn = "int",
    DiscriminatorType = "type",
    DiscriminatorValue = "0")]
public class Detail<T> : ActiveRecordValidationBase<T>, IDetail where T : class
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo]
    public ContactInformation ParentContactInformation { get; set; }

public interface IDetail
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    ContactInformation ParentContactInformation { get; set; } 
}
```

The following exception:

```
SetUp : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.XmlGenerationVisitor.WriteCompositeColumns(String[] columns)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.XmlGenerationVisitor.WriteCollection(ManyRelationCascadeEnum cascadeEnum, Type targetType, RelationType type, String name, String accessString, String table, String schema, Boolean lazy, Boolean inverse, String orderBy, String where, String sort, String columnKey, String[] compositeKeyColumnKeys, String element, Type elementType, String columnRef, String[] compositeKeyColumnRefs, IVisitable extraModel, String index, String indexType, CacheEnum cache, String cacheregion, NotFoundBehaviour notFoundBehaviour, FetchEnum fetch, Int32 batchSize, Type collectionType)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.XmlGenerationVisitor.VisitHasMany(HasManyModel model)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.HasManyModel.Accept(IVisitor visitor)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.AbstractDepthFirstVisitor.VisitNodes(IEnumerable nodes)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.XmlGenerationVisitor.VisitModel(ActiveRecordModel model)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.XmlGenerationVisitor.CreateXml(ActiveRecordModel model)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.AddXmlToNHibernateCfg(ISessionFactoryHolder holder, ActiveRecordModelCollection models)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.RegisterTypes(ISessionFactoryHolder holder, IConfigurationSource source, IEnumerable`1 types, Boolean ignoreProblematicTypes)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(IConfigurationSource source, Type[] types)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(Assembly[] assemblies, IConfigurationSource source, Type[] additionalTypes)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(Assembly assembly, IConfigurationSource source)
at tests.Framework.ModelTests.SetUpFixture() in ModelTests.cs: line 18
```

This is my SetUpFixture

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void SetUpFixture()
{
    if (ActiveRecordStarter.IsInitialized) return;

    IConfigurationSource source = ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance;
    ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(Assembly.Load("Model"), source);
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

I checked the files generated and details files has this filename Detail`1.hbm.xml backtick and this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<hibernate-mapping  auto-import="true" default-lazy="false" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Model.Contact.Detail`1, Model" table="Details" discriminator-value="0">
    <id name="Id" access="property" column="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native">
      </generator>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="type" type="int" />

    <property name="Owner" access="property" type="String">
      <column name="Owner"/>
    </property>
    <property name="Location" access="property" type="String">
      <column name="Location"/>
    </property>
    <property name="ContactDetail" access="property" type="String">
      <column name="ContactDetail"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="ParentContactInformation" access="property" class="Model.ContactInformation,Model" column="ParentContactInformation" lazy="proxy" />
    <subclass name="Model.Contact.Email, Model" discriminator-value="3">
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="Model.Contact.Phone, Model" discriminator-value="1">
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="Model.Contact.Fax, Model" discriminator-value="2">
    </subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some testing I found out that I can use generic classes. The problem was that I had to move

```
[BelongsTo]
public ContactInformation ParentContactInformation { get; set; }
```

from my Detail class to the the child class (email) for some reason the BelongsTo needs to be in the children.

Comment: the underlying issue is still there: it doesn't make sense to map open generic classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to map a class with an undefined type parameter (i.e. an open generic class). You need to map concrete classes. See this for more information:

- [Mapping Generic Classes using NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797836/mapping-generic-classes-using-nhibernate)
- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/14/NHibernate-and-Generic-Entities.aspx

Comment: I changed my Detail model to public class Detail : ActiveRecordValidationBase, IDetail - but I am getting the same exception as before with the same pattern it works sometimes and not some other times. When it works now the filename is correct without the backtick